# How to add external CSS or JS file on joomla Helix framework

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5

Try something like that:

```
templates->shaper_helix_ii->index.php 

->addLess('master', 'template')
->addcss('demo', 'template')
->addLess( 'presets',  'presets/'.$this->helix->Preset() );
```

What's wrong this code. i can't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding custom css and javascript files:

```
->addLess('master', 'template')
->addLess('presets',  'presets/'.$this->helix->Preset())
->addJs('main.js,demo.js')
->addCSS('demo.css,template.css');
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a module instead of inserting it on a template since template updates usually will break your previous changes. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/flexi-custom-code that module will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the plugin "JQuery Easy" , if you go to Advanced Settings, you can include or exclude any css or js files you want and you can also choose what pages to exclude from the plugin to work! Pretty simple :)